# outlook-addin html body support for outlook for mac 16.24

Tags: macos, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

I am developing outlook add-in on Outlook for mac 16.24(19041401). I tried to insert html to meeting body. The html is href for skype in . When end user tried to use add-in change the the skype number, I tried to use outlook-addin to read the meeting html body. But I got 2 issues. 
1. "" isn't in the html body like I inserted into the body. 
2. The Skype href doesn't have "skype://xxxxx?call", just give me a . Anybody have the same issue with me?

I insert the body:

```
<div id="skypelink" style="vertical-align:middle;display: inline-block">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
<span><a href="skype:123456?call" style="color: #1AB394;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;">Join Call</a></span>
</div>
```

Use outlook read the html body:

```
 <p class=MsoNormal style='vertical-align:middle'><img border=0 width=13
 height=13 style='width:.1354in;height:.1354in'
 src="~WRS%7b2F8FB628-6315-8E46-8398-0F1A181C67F9%7d.fld/image006.jpg"
 style='height:.135in;width:.135in'
 alt="/var/folders/63/dwr3c3t12szbjc66m_kxk5300000gp/T/com.microsoft.Outlook/Content.MSO/41334F0E.tmp"><span
 style='font-family:"Microsoft YaHei UI",serif'><span class=MsoHyperlink><span
 style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#1AB394'>Join Call</span></span></span><span style='font-family:"Microsoft YaHei UI",serif'> </span></p>
```